# How can I add qrcode to .doc office document?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, qr-code

I download the file on the client and send it to the server where I digitally sign it. Next, after signing, I try to create a qrcode in a document from the signature certificate data. On the Internet, as such, I could not find information. Please tell me what are the options for adding qrcode to the document